# How to have the origins of the exe size in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I sometimes try to understand what constitute the size of my exe in Delphi. 
For it I use Gexpert 'Project Analyser' but when I sum all the size of the Code+Data+Ressource I never have my exe size (I have more or less 70% of it). I try it on a simple project without embeded images or others.

So : what am I missing ? And what is the good way to list all the 'pieces' of my exe ?

Comment: You should generate a map file for more reliable details.

Comment: @user539484 Yes, but map file is not really easy to use...

Comment: programming is not really easy at all.

Comment: Yep, but, sometimes, I want to believe in Miracle of Christmas...

Comment: Speaking of miracles, you can grab JCL debug expert code which processes map files and make reporting tool of your taste on the top of it. Meanwhile, did you confirm the difference between map and GExperts report?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quick and dirty way that can be used is to open the executable with 7-zip .

It shows each sections along with their length using PE format.

Comment: Good idea, I never used 7zip for it !